# Cannot connect to VM Socket closed

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Error message when starting application in eclipse.

When trying to upload the application in eclipse, a popup appears with the message "Cannot connect to VM Socket closed" and it cannot start.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me.

Make sure the warsaw application is installed. If so, uninstall it. Any other security application for internet banking access could be causing this. Uninstall. Here I had the same problem after installing my bank's security application.

For those who are Brazilian like me, uninstall the security program from Caixa Econômica (Warsaw). Here this was the cause.